# amcharts v4 - How to get series and bullet elements from an XY chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, amcharts, amcharts4

Let's say an XY chart is created like this :

```js
let charts = [];

function createChart() {
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

  // Create chart instance
  let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  // Add data
  chart.data = [{
    "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
    "value": 450,
    "showTooltip": "always"
  }, ...,
  {
    "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
    "value": 500,
    "showTooltip": "always",
    "orientation": "up",
    "offset": 5
  }];

  // Create axes
  let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

  ...

  let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

  // Create series
  let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());

  ...

  let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());

  ...

  charts.push(chart);
}

function modifyTooltip() {
  let chart = charts[0];

  // How to get the first bullet, second bullet, third bullet of the XY chart?
  let bullets = chart.series.bullet; // <- undefined
}
```

The objective is to modify the first, second, and third bullets tooltip display, in `function modifyTooltip()` :

```js
bullets.propertyFields.showTooltipOn = "showTooltip";
```

The chart and the first, second, and third bullets look like this :

[image]

Reference : [Codepen - amcharts v4 XYchart example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/embed/zgZPPB?default-tab=result&editable=true&theme-id=dark)

Is there any methods to loop through all bullets in the line series so one can modify tooltip property of particular bullet using `propertyFields`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, everything is scriptable, `chart`, `series`, `bullet`, etc; the documentation is starts at https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/tag/class/, e.g., [series#bullets](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/series/#bullets_property) or [bullet class](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/bullet/). In [this fork of the standard example](https://codepen.io/kikondo/pen/QWVrJYP?editors=1010) I added a buttin that changes the tooltip text for all bullets.

Comment: @kikon Thanks for the example! How do you get an element of a chart (like bullet) from a global variable (in this case, `charts[0]`)? I tried `let bullet = charts[0].series.bullets;` but it was undefined.

Comment: `charts[0].series` is a collection, i.e., a [ListTemplate](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/) (same as `.bullets`) so you have to use its `.values` array to get an item, something like `charts[0].series.values[0].bullets.values[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what got series and bullet elements :

```js
...

function modifyTooltip() {
  // Get series element from XY chart
  let series = charts[0].series.getIndex(0);
  
  // Get bullets element from series
  let bullets = series.bullets.getIndex(0);

  // Only display tooltip on particular bullets
  bullets.propertyFields.showTooltipOn = "showTooltip";
}
```

Particular bullets, in this case, refer to Bullet 1, Bullet 2, and Bullet 3, as illustrated in the picture.

---

Explanation of :

```js
// Get series element from XY chart
let series = charts[0].series.getIndex(0);
```

[Amcharts v4 XY chart docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#series_property) states it has series property.

Series property's type is [ListTemplate](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#getIndex_method) which can be obtained with `getIndex()` method.

Explanation of :

```js
// Get bullets element from series
let bullets = series.bullets.getIndex(0);
```

Series has a property named bullets, per [Amcharts v4 series docs](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/series/#bullets_property). Bullets, just like series, is [ListTemplate type](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#getIndex_method). That means, one can retrieve it using `getIndex()` method.

Explanation of :

```js
// Only display tooltip on particular bullets
bullets.propertyFields.showTooltipOn = "showTooltip";
```

> "How come `bullets.propertyFields.showTooltipOn = "showTooltip";` can
> select certain bullets (Bullet 1, Bullet 2, and Bullet 3) ?"

The key is in the `chart.data`. It should look something like this :

```js
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 450,
  "showTooltip": "always"
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
  "value": 269,
  "showTooltip": "always"
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
  "value": 700,
  "showTooltip": "always"
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 4),
  "value": 490
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
  "value": 500
}];
```

**The first three elements of `chart.data` contains `showTooltip` property which determines if the bullet that represents that element should display tooltip or not**.

Note:
property name can be other than `showTooltip`.

Let's say the property name is `isTooltipShown`.

```js
chart.data = [{
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 1),
  "value": 450,
  "isTooltipShown": "always"
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 2),
  "value": 269,
  "isTooltipShown": "always"
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 3),
  "value": 700,
  "isTooltipShown": "always"
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 4),
  "value": 490
}, {
  "date": new Date(2018, 0, 5),
  "value": 500
}];
```

Accordingly, the one in `function modifyTooltip()` should be :

```js
...
// Only display tooltip on particular bullets
bullets.propertyFields.showTooltipOn = "isTooltipShown";
```

Another key is the `propertyFields`. This is crucial when overriding a property of an item in series with a value from data. Learn more: [Amcharts v4 - Selective Sticky Tooltips](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/using-sticky-tooltips/#Selective_sticky_tooltips).